# Finding a quartic polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ with four real roots such that Galois group is ${S_4}$.

Tags: galois-theory

Is there a quartic polynomial $p(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ irreducible with four real roots such that Galois group is ${S_4}$?

If it really exists, can someone give me a example?

Comment: The most obvious are the ones with roots of the form $\pm a\pm\sqrt b$

Comment: @Lucian, but aren't those reducible?

Comment: Thanks @Lucian. I had starded with the roots too, but i was using $\pm \sqrt{p} \pm\sqrt{q} $ with p,q primes. In your answer 'b' should be a prime, for it does not to be reducible.

Comment: @lhf: Believe it or not, some 12 hours ago, *Mathematica* was telling me that $x^4-6x^2+1$ $($the polynomial corresponding to $a=1$ and $b=2)$ is irreducible. Now, she's suddenly able to factor it. :-$)$  But if we change *a* with $\sqrt a$, where both *a* and *b* are not perfect squares, it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As hinted in the comments to [a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007243/)
and as shown in [Keith Conrad's notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/cubicquartic.pdf),
a degree-$4$ polynomial from $K[X]$, where $K$ is a field with $\operatorname{char}K\not\in\{2,3\}$,
has Galois group $S_4$ if

- it is irreducible over $K$
  (thus its Galois group has order divisible by $4$), and
- its [resolvent cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_cubic)
  is irreducible over $K$
  (thus the Galois group has order divisible by $3$), and
- its [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant)
  is not a square in $K$ (thus the Galois group is not a subgroup of $A_4$).

Now consider
$$f(X) = X^4 - 6 X^2 + 2 X + 2$$
which changes sign between $-\infty,-1,0,+1,+\infty$
and therefore has four real roots.

$f(X)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion)
with $p=2$.
Therefore its Galois group has order divisible by $4$.

The resolvent cubic of $f(X)$ is
$$\begin{align}
g(X) &= X^3 + 6 X^2 - 8 X - 52 &
g(X-2) &= X^3 - 20 X - 20
\end{align}$$
so $g(X-2)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein's criterion
with $p=5$, thus $g(X)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ as well.
The extension degree of the splitting field of $g(X)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$
is therefore divisible by $3$.
By construction of the resolvent cubic,
the splitting field of $g(X)$ is contained in the splitting field of $f(X)$,
so the order of the Galois group of $f(X)$ must be divisible by $3$.

Again by construction, the discriminant of $f(X)$
equals the discriminant of $g(X)$ and of $g(X-2)$, which is
$$\Delta=21200$$
You easily recognize the square $100$ as a factor,
but the cofactor $212\equiv2\pmod{5}$ is not a square.
Therefore $\Delta$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}$.
Consequently, the Galois group of $f(X)$ is not a subgroup of $A_4$.

Summarizing the above results, the Galois group of $f(X)$ has order
divisible by $3$ and $4$, yet is not a subgroup of $A_4$.
This leaves $S_4$ as only possible Galois group for $f(X)$.

Comment: Example with somewhat smaller discriminant: $f(X)=X^4-4X^2+X+1$, changing signs between $-\infty,-1,0,+1,+\infty$, irreducible $\bmod{2}$, resolvent cubic $g(X)=X^3+4X^2-4X-17$, irreducible $\bmod{3}$, $\Delta=1957$.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about the same question but with a polynomial with degree 3 and $S_3$, in this case, it is not possible, right?

Comment: For a degree-$3$ polynomial with real roots and Galois group $S_3$: By Keith Conrad's notes, you will find that then $f(X)$ just needs to be irreducible (thus $3$ divides the group order) and have nonsquare positive discriminant (thus it is not $A_3$, and all roots are real). Therefore, the $g(X)$ and $g(X-2)$ given above can serve as examples.