# (Why) do most irreducible quartic polynomials with four real roots over $\mathbb Q$ have galois group $A_4$?

Tags: galois-theory

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2069258/1148680) it is claimed that most irreducible quartic polynomials with four real roots over $\mathbb Q$ have galois group $A_4$. What do they mean by this and (why) is what they mean true?

Comment: Compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340103/finding-a-quartic-polynomial-in-mathbbqx-with-four-real-roots-such-that-g). If the discriminant is a square then the Galois group is $A_4$ in this theorem from the answer (and $S_4$, if it is not a square). I would say, that being a square is not "generic", so usually I would expect $S_4$ as Galois group (but I don't know what they mean exactly).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Why does the discriminant not being a square imply the Galois group to be $S_4$?

Comment: This is the cited Theorem in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340103/finding-a-quartic-polynomial-in-mathbbqx-with-four-real-roots-such-that-g), as I said, with the reference to a detailed proof in Conrad's notes, namely Corollary $4.3$ on page $12$ with table $8$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde In that table there are also a rows where the discriminant is not a square and the Galois groups is $\mathbb Z/(4)$ or $D_4$ rather than $S_4$.

Comment: I mean, with the same conditions of the answer in the duplicate, for $A_4$ (in comparison to $S_4$), so with $R_3(x)$ irreducible. In other words, we are discussing only the first two rows in table $8$. We are not interested in $D_4$, $C_4$ or $V$. So my first comment only says, that $S_4$ should be more likely than $A_4$.