# Splitting field of $X^4+X^3+1\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

I am interested in the splitting field $L$ of $f=X^4+X^3+1\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

As we can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146310/galois-group-of-x4x31-over-mathbbq), we have $Gal(f)\cong S_4$ by using Dedekind's Theorem (Question 1: Can we obtain this result without using this theorem?). So  $[L:\mathbb Q]=24$. We can also see that $f$ doesn't have real roots so it factors to $f=(X-\alpha)(X-\overline{\alpha})(X-\beta)(X-\overline{\beta})$. Therefore we should be able to conclude $L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$. Now there must be an error in my train of thought since this field can at most have degree $4\cdot 4$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Question 2: What is the correct splitting field?

Comment: This is answered  in K. Conrad's [notes](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjduvSV76HWAhWDB8AKHfhQD38QFghnMAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fgaloistheory%2Fcubicquartic.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGI4_d1S21mFaiShArghp8yQFIwdg), section $3$. The splitting field contains both a cubic subfield, and a quartic one. This already implies that $12=3\cdot 4\mid |Gal(f)|$, so that it must be $A_4$ or $S_4$. It is easy to see that it is $S_4$.

Comment: Thanks, I can see that one can obtain the galois group using resolvents. But what about question 2?

Comment: I don't want a cubic subfield. I want the splitting field and I want to know whether my $L$ is correct or not.

Comment: But you need to know about cubic subfields of your splitting field, to find the splitting field. Further problem: $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ need not be a Galois extension - see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287643/is-mathbbq-sqrt33-sqrt43-a-galois-extension-of-mathbbq). You need to adjoin another root, too. If you follow Conrad's text, you will be done.

Comment: For getting $L$, it is not sufficient to adjoin $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Have a look at the conjugate fields of ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ to see your error.